# 2d motion field

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, motion

I have a theoretical question regarding motion field within a scenario and have searched the internet to get the answer though have been unsuccessful in doing so.

If I have a camera in my hand and I translate it horizontally from right to left. If there is a tall pole to in the foreground and a small tree far away in the background, what would the motion field show? Would it easily recognise two distinct motion fields or would it only recognise the pole in the foreground?

At first I thought it would show two distinct motion fields recognising both, the pole and the small tree, however, now I am confused on whether the tree would appear as a constant motion (just like the background) and would not have a motion field.

Would highly appreciate your response. Thanks.